# Matlab function error

Tags: matlab

I am fairly new to matlab and am working through some examples, I have the code:

```
function [T,Y] = heun(f,a,b,ya,m)
h = (b - a)/m;
T = zeros(1,m+1);
Y = zeros(1,m+1);
T(1) = a;
Y(1) = ya;
for j=1:m,
    k1 = feval(f,T(j),Y(j));
    p  = Y(j) + h*k1;
    T(j+1) = a + h*j;
    k2 = feval(f,T(j+1),p);
    Y(j+1) = Y(j) + h*(k1 + k2)/2;
end
```

obtained from: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/2181-numerical-methods-using-matlab-2e/content/edition2/matlab/chap_9/heun.m

and i get the error "heun" requires more input arguments to run, it is save as an m file named heun, I am trying to adapt this method for a different problem but can't get this code to work can anyone help?

Comment: Can you show us how you are *using* this function ?

Comment: well I want to plot Y vs T using this method

Comment: We're not looking for an explanation of what you "want". We want you to show us the commands you are using to execute heun(). How did you make it run?

Comment: Show us the line your are writing !

Comment: I guess then plot(T,Y);

Comment: How did you make `heun()` run? The command `plot(T,Y)` is not what you used to cause the function heun() to run. It doesn't have `heun` anywhere in it.

Comment: well I originally just used the run button on the toolbar, without the plot bit because i just wanted to see if it worked,

Comment: Since you are a MATLAB beginner, do not use the run button. Run heun from the command line, passing it the 5 input quantities it requires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think there is some basic misunderstanding of the function usage in Matlab.
Maybe you understand the problem if I give you an example of how you use your function.

1- Save your function as posted above into a new Matlab function** called heun.m

2- Write your function you'd like to evaluate. As you'd like to make use of Heun's method you should be familiar with the sense of that function... The function needs to have two input parameters and return one output parameter. One could describe it as *out = myFunction(in1, in2)*

3- You save your function as a Matlab function** into the same directory as heun.m and name it for example myFunction.m

4- Now you create a new Matlab script** and name it however you want. In this script you can call your function heun.m (which is itself calculating something with your function myFunction...). You call heun.m for example with these lines:

```
f = @myFunction; % or: f = 'myFunction';
a = -2;
b = 3;
ya = 2;
m = 4;

[T,Y] = heun(f, a, b, ya, m);
```

by the way: @myFunction is in this case a function handle. You can find further information on the mathworks homepage or use the alternative I wrote as a comment.

**I hope you know the basic difference between a Matlab script and a Matlab function. If not have a look on these pages:
http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-scripts.html
http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/matlab_prog/scripts-and-functions.html

function, function, function... Well, despite of the frequent usage of the word 'function' I hope I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are calling heun() with 5 input arguments. In the code you've shown f,a,b,ya,m are the 5 quantities that heun() expects to receive.

Comment: is it because m is defined anywhere? I'm not really sure what you mean

Comment: When you invoke the function, you should be sending it 5 inputs, as in `heun(f,a,b,ya,m)`

Comment: sorry im fairly new to matlab, do you mean just putting quote marks either side of heun?

Comment: Edit your question and show how you're invoking heun() right now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with the code you are showing us, but with **the way you are using it**

Has you can see from the link you gave,

```
% Sample call
%   [T,Y] = heun('f',a,b,ya,m)
% Inputs
%   f    name of the function
%   a    left  endpoint of [a,b]
%   b    right endpoint of [a,b]
%   ya   initial value
%   m    number of steps
% Return
%   T    solution: vector of abscissas
%   Y    solution: vector of ordinates
```

to use this function you need to give it the 5 *Input* parameters. We can't do anything unless you show us the code which call `heun`.